# Why generated code in C# uses underscore?

Tags: c#, private, members

I know this might be a stupid question, but here it goes. 
I always wrote my private members like `privateMember` and I've been reading a lot about naming conventions in C# because I noticed that a lot of the automatic generated code in visual studio use `_variableName` for private members. Everywhere I read, even in Microsoft documents, that you should use `privateMember`.
So, my question is, if the good practices says that I should write `privateMember`, as I do now, Why the heck Visual Studio generates classes with private members using underscore (`_privateMember`)?

Comment: As an aside, one reason for prefixing member variables with an underscore is that they appear at the top of the intellisense list. I personally hate it, as the keyboard stretch to get an underscore character is really awkward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not so long time ago when C# was raising to the market there was a concept that local variables should be leaded by a prefix `_`. This concept was not accepted by the community as in pure C the `_` leads system variable/functions  and the metadata are lead by `__`. So after few years, they now discourage to use that. But still you will find some believer that use this notation not because it is a fanatic but a lot of old C# applications contain this convention.

Why this is in VisualStudio ?

This might be related to the time gap it was designed. In those time this approach was suggested by language designers. So it is probably that no one changed that in the configuration for latest version.

Answer (score 6):

[Microsoft Code Conventions actually recommend against using underscores altogether](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx). It is really personal preference. I would not use generated code as inspiration for my coding convention standard.

> **Do not use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric characters.**

Maybe it's because it's generated code and not intended to be read by humans. ;-)

Comment: kudos for finding this reference. I agree with everything in there except for the underscore, to me it's easier to scan a class if all the private fields are prefixed with an underscore.

Comment: The above link is referring to publicly exposed APIs (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) - **not** `private`.

Answer (score 5):

Naming conventions aren't 100% agreed upon.  This is one of those that some people like, some people are indifferent to, and some people hate.  Certain people consider it better for instance variables to stand out, via their name, and this is one way to do that.  Other people use `this.instanceVariable` rather than `instanceVariable` all of the time so that instance variables stand out, other people prepend something other than a '_' character, and some people just don't go out of their way to use any special distinction.

At the end of the day what's important is that you, and the other members of your team agree on a standard and are consistent with it.  What the rest of the world chooses to do doesn't need to affect you.

It's also worth mentioning that the code snippets generated by Visual Studio, in most cases, can be configured to be in line with your team's coding practices.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a convention they use, I do it too. You can ultimately name your private fields whatever you want. Prefixing it with an underscore just makes it easier to read IMO.

Comment: Please read the whole question not only the topic.

Comment: @Vash that's a pretty big assumption, I did read the question. I just understood the **why** to mean something different than you did. You have have the accepted answer, you win.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the C# language convention so that in constructor you can use _varable instead of this.variable, when the constructor and field name is the same.

there are all c# naming conventions in
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx

It's a mather of you if you follow the convention of the generated code.
Besisdes the recomendations many programmers use the same convention as the generated code.
Some programs that help you refactor the code also sugests you to follow that name convention for field names.

Comment: Please read the whole question not only the topic.

Comment: I did, I just completed a lil more my answer then

Comment: So You do not understood it. In your answer is nothing about the Visial Studio and generated code that question is about.

Answer (score 0):

As a convention private fields were/is used as with underscore e.g. string _name;

The link will give you more info on guidelines for naming coventions by MS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx

Comment: Ironically, that link actually recommends *against* it.

Comment: Correct it does recommends against it hence i said private fields were/is used with underscore and copied the link for you

Answer (score 0):

The underscore at the beginning is VS's way of showing that it is a privateMember.  We keep the underscore at the beginning as a rule, but it is really a personal preference as to what naming convention you use.  Just pick one and stick with it so you don't confuse yourself or anyone else that might look at your code.